# Bash: How to read the script when sourcing it

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, files

When bash is executing a script, `ls -la /proc/<pid of bash>/fd` shows "255 -> /path/to/script".
I think that bash reads the script via file discriptor 255, and executes the commands line by line.

But when bash is sourcing a script, I can't find such an entry in `ls -la /proc/<pid of bash>/fd`.
I can't find in `cat /proc/<pid of bash>/maps`, either.

I have a question: When bash sources a script, how does bash read the script? Is there any special way to read the script file?

Comment: *When bash sources a script, how does bash read the script* I would think the commands are read in the same way as when you type commands in your shell. when you run a script, another shell process is created but when you source a script you are using the same shell process and for that reason you don't see the file descriptor. I think that but if I'm wrong it should be useful someone provide the correct answer. It's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I hit upon an idea to analyze the situation by `strace`.

When just executing, the output of `strace -f -p <pid>` is like this:

> openat(AT_FDCWD, "./test", O_RDONLY) = 3
>
> ...
>
> [pid  3408] dup2(3, 255)                = 255
>
> [pid  3408] close(3)                    = 0

"test" is the shell script to be executed.
"3408" is the pid of the child shell.
"test" is opened at file discriptor 3, and dupulicated to file discriptor 255.
So `ls -la /proc/<pid of bash>/fd` shows "255 -> /some/directory/test".

But when sourcing the script, "test" is opened, read into the buffer, and immediately closed. So `ls -la /proc/<pid of bash>/fd` show no such entry as above.

I don't know why bash is implemented like this.